# Trigger click effect when another component is clicked in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a card in a row. Both are clickable, but when I click either one of them I want the other to trigger the click effect also.

Is it possible to do this?

[image]

This is my code so far

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun GlobalSettingItem(
    iconDrawable: Int,
    title: Int,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable(enabled = true, onClick = onClick),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
    ) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 4.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
                .size(50.dp),
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.myTheme.background,
            shape = CircleShape,
            onClick = { },
            elevation = 0.dp,
        ) {
            Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = iconDrawable),
                    contentDescription = "Settings Icon",
                    tint = MaterialTheme.myTheme.colorAccent,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(24.dp)
                        .height(24.dp),
                )
            }
        }
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 4.dp),
            text = stringResource(title),
            color = MaterialTheme.myTheme.onBackground,
            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp),
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use android studio just because you're using it to make your app, use `android` instead

Comment: I need more context to help, some code snippets, for example. I'll try, though. If they have the same functionality, you could make a single method e.g. click(), which runs in both click listeners. If they have different functions, make two methods, e.g. cardClick() and rowClick() and include both in each other's click listener.

Comment: What is it you want both the `Row` and `Card` to do onClick? You have already [hoisted](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting) the onClick fn to the parent Composable.

Comment: Basically I want the onClick of both to do the same thing, navigate somewhere in the app based on the setting that is clicked. There will be multiple settings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To synchronize the "click effect" in multiple `Composables` you need to share the same `InteractionSource` object between them, so they can react to the same state.
By default every clickable element creates (and `remembers`) their state separately, but you can always pass it to it, from the outside if you wish to have more control over it.

Both `Modifier.clickable` and `Card` have variants where you can pass `interactionSource`. In `clickable` you also need to pass `indication`, because that parameter has no default value (like in `Card`), but that value is just taken from `LocalIndication.current`.

I think you should also assign your `onClick` in `Card`, otherwise it would consume clicks and do nothing with it. Which is probably not what you want, but I'm not sure about your intention here.

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun GlobalSettingItem(
    iconDrawable: Int,
    title: Int,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable(
                enabled = true,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = LocalIndication.current,
                onClick = onClick
            ),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
    ) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 4.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
                .size(50.dp),
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.myTheme.background,
            shape = CircleShape,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            onClick = onClick,
            elevation = 0.dp,
        ) {
            Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = iconDrawable),
                    contentDescription = "Settings Icon",
                    tint = MaterialTheme.myTheme.colorAccent,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(24.dp)
                        .height(24.dp),
                )
            }
        }
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 4.dp),
            text = stringResource(title),
            color = MaterialTheme.myTheme.onBackground,
            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as I wanted.